# RIA Services Code Generation in Silverlight application

Tags: c#, silverlight, ria, domainservices

Is there any way to avoid code generation for types that are already referenced when using multiple domains?

Let me explain.

---

I have an application infrastacture for silverlight application. This infra package includes 3 (RIA) domain services (authentication, logging, service discovery) on the server side - **Infra.Web.dll** and a silverlight dll - **ClientInfra.dll** that implements user authentication at the application start and some other base classes (like BaseApp and BaseView) while **Infra.Web.dll** is defined as WCF RIA Services Link for **ClientInfra.dll**.

Now I'm developping some demo silverlight application in order to test my infrastructura. I have created the

**DemoApp.Web** wich refernces the  **Infra.Web.dll** (in order to get the infra services)

and 2 silverlight projects:

**DemoApp.Data** that defines  **DemoApp.Web.dll** as WCF RIA Services Link in order to get the generated code and refrences **ClientInfra.dll**

**DemoApp** that is the actual silverlight application that refernces **ClientInfra.dll**

The problem is that when I try to use one of the RIA services from the silverlight application I've got an error that the Domain Service classes are defined both in **ClientInfra.dll** and  **DemoApp.Data**. As far as I understand the problem is the code from **Infra.Web.dll** has been generated twice: first for **ClientInfra.dll**, second for **DemoApp.Data**.

Is there any way to avoid code generation for types that are allready refrenced like in my case where  **ClientInfra.dll** allready has the generated infra services so there is no need to generate it again in **DemoApp.Data**?

I'll try to make my question more simple. How can I avoid the ria services type generation (in silverlight) of types that have been already generated for my referenced dll? The type generation duplication causes an error CS0433 that the same types are defined in 2 different dll's

I have found out some interesting fact.  If I reference the  **ClientInfra.dll** directly from the **DemoApp** (the silverlight application project) than the data types that have been alresdy generated in **ClientInfra.dll** are not generated once more. But if  I reference the  **ClientInfra.dll** from **DemoApp.Data** I do get the duplicated types code generation with a compilation warning that the same types are defined both in the referenced dll and in the generated code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the following in the msdn documentation

> Analyze all assemblies either built or referenced by the middle tier
>   project for domain service classes, entity classes, or shared code.
>
> RIA Services checks the existing members before generating the proxy
>   class. Any member that is already defined will not be generated in the
>   proxy class.

That means that my scenario should work as I have expected!

In order to check the code generation process I set the MSBuild project to build *output verbosity* (Tool->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run) to Normal (instead of default Minimal). Then after the compilation I discovered that the **DemoApp.Data** project had failed to load **ClientInfra.dll** that includes already generated proxies. So the generator just ignored it and generated all the classes from the beginning.

I have solved this loading issue and everything works fine now.

Comment: Its crazy the amount of good information that is hidden in the Minimal configuration. Wrong reference on dependency project, so dependency silently failed to build and no errors at all! Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar infrastructure, but I exposed the DomainServices with SOAP and consume the services in other apps, So , I should you to do the same with your projects.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. The problem is that I have tens of applications and I don't want all of them to consume the same services, it creates a bottle neck for me. I'd like to make every application to serve itself.